# Kafka Spring Consuming Messages which are not Consumed

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

Learning Kafka and I want to know if there is any way to consume messages which have been queued/unconsumed when a API is down.

For example
I send a messages {1,2,3,4,5} to the topic when API is down
Start the API and the consumer should consume the messages {1,2,3,4,5}

Currently

```java
@Service
public class ConsumerService {

  private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConsumerService.class);

  @KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic-name}", groupId = "${kafka.group-id}")
  public void consume(String message) {
    logger.info(String.format("Message recieved -> %s", message));
  }
}
```

but this only consumes messages when the API is up and running

Comment: What "API" are you talking about? If the listener is not running, records will accumulate in the topic and will be consumed the next time it is started. For the first time, you need to set `auto.offset.reset` to `earliest` - otherwise the consumer will consume only from the end of the topic `latest`.

Comment: @GaryRussell the consumer service - so for example currently if ConsumerService is not running and I post a few messages on the topic and start the service again - it does not show the previous messages

Comment: As I said, you need to set the `auto.offset.reset` consumer property to `earliest`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

auto.offset.rest property will resolve your issue. But you should know how it works in the runtime.

### Use Case 1:

A consumer starts and has auto.offset.reset=latest, and the topic partition currently has data for offsets going from some range to other. The consumer group has committed the some offsetfor the topic before. Where will the consumer read from?

Ans : The offsets are already committed for this consumer group and topic partition, so the property auto.offset.reset is ignored

### Use Case 2:

A consumer starts and has auto.offset.reset=none, and the topic partition currently has data for offsets going from some range to other. The consumer group has committed some offsets for the topic before. Where will the consumer read from?

Ans: auto.offset.reset=none means that the consumer will crash if the offsets it's recovering from have been deleted from Kafka.

### Use Case 3:

A consumer has auto.offset.reset=latest, and the topic partition currently has data for offsets going from some range to other. The consumer group never committed offsets for the topic before. Where will the consumer read from?

Ans: Latest means that data retrievals will start from where the offsets currently end.

Answer (score 0):

> this only consumes messages when the API is up and running

Of course, but what offsets are those messages?

It should read starting from the last committed offset. For example, start the service, send 1,2,3. Stop the service. Send 4,5. Start the service.